# set an attribute in XML node usig MSXML. I am struck

Tags: c++, msxml, setattribute

I try to set an attribute in a XML node using MSXML. `IXMLDOMElement` alone has the member function `setAttribute`. So I got the document element.

```
pXMLDocumentElement -> get_documentElement (& pElement );
pElement -> selectSingleNode ( nodePathString ,& pNode );
.
.
.
pElement -> setAttribute ( bstr , var );
```

I selected the required node in which the attribute has to be set using `selectSingleNode` function. After selecting the required node, I tried to set attribute.

But the `PElement` pointer does not shift to the required node. It stayed on the root node. Result: added the attribute in root itself.

Is there any way, I can shift my `PElement` to the node resulted in `selectSingleNode` function? So that I can set the attribute.

Comment: A question with a mistake in the code. Submitting to close as `too localized`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use the `setAttributeNode` API on your `pNode` pointer.

While you are at it read [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169461&seqNum=6) tutorial on using MSXML. And after you have the basics covered [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/davids/archive/2008/12/20/msxml-in-c-but-as-elegant-as-c.aspx) blog.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just use the funcion `get_documentElement`, then you will get the root node in the DOM, the root pointer is stored in the `pElement`, and you call the `setAttribute` function by using the pointer `pElement`,so the attribute of root  will always be set